# Numbered dynamic library files instead of just ".so" file

Tags: shared-libraries, embedded-linux, grpc

For embedded Linux, I try to build grpc package.

After all, I only find numbered dynamic library files instead of just `.so` file like below.

- How I do know which numbered files need to be linked when linking using "-l" option for C++?
- Also, how do I use "-l" option for numbered library files? 
  Could it be like "-lgrpc++.so.1"?

Thank you.

```
===below===
no "libgrpc++.so" but there are only:
libgrpc++.so.1
libgrpc++.so.1.8.5
```

//Daum